# Why these chemical reactions do not occur?

Tags: reaction-mechanism

I have this list of reactions which don't occur:
$$\ce{MgCl2(aq)} + \ce{K2SO4(aq)}$$
$$\ce{Fe(NO3)2(aq)} + \ce{SnCl4(aq)}$$
$$\ce{Cu(NO3)2(aq)} + \ce{FeBr3(aq)}$$
$$\ce{KCl(aq)} + \ce{CuSO4(aq)}$$

I would like to know why and how can I recognise when a reaction occurs or it does not.

***My thought***: I think the products are salts, which they remain dissolved in water. In this case reactions would not happen because we are considering an aqueous solution. Am I right?

Comment: I think you have the write idea. The reactions you are looking at in this case are double replacement reactions. The starting reactants exist in solution as their component ions so unless a particular pair of ions is insoluble when they are mixed, they will just remain ions.